# Codsworth stuck under a building

Tags: fallout-4

Fallout 4, via Steam, on PC, all DLCs. A few creation club mods. The "Unofficial Fallout 4 Patch" mod. Survival mode.

I was travelling with Codsworth as my companion, when I decided to dismiss him. I sent him to Hangman's Alley.

I'm now attempting to get him as my companion again. I used the "Vault-Tec Population Management System" to track him (the Unofficial patch fixes the bug where you can't track him in the base game), but when I tracked him down he's apparently floating *underneath* a building next to the settlement.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Here's the PIP Boy map showing his location relative to the settlement:

[image: PIP Boy Map]

How do I get him out from under the building?

I tried sleeping for a period of time, hoping he would respawn inside of the settlement, but that didn't make a difference. The only similar issue I found on Reddit was Codsworth [getting stuck under the ocean](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/a5v8z3/comment/ebq34np/), but the only resolution offered in that thread were console commands. I'm looking for a console-free option since I'm on Survival.

Comment: Yes, I know there's a way to use the console in Survival by dropping out of Survival, doing the commands, and then using the console to reenable Survival, but I'd rather not do that since it smacks of cheating to me. :(

Comment: Does this work? https://help.bethesda.net/#en/answer/31451 - note that this refers to *travelling* to other areas, rather than staying in the same one and sleeping.

Comment: Hm. That seems to rely on the idea that when you come back to a cell/settlement after it's been unloaded from memory, the engine will re-place the NPCs based on places where it thinks they could reasonably belong (which is why we end up with settlers and cows on the roofs and stuck in doorways.) I'm not sure how that'll jive with the fact that I'm actively tracking Codsworth's position on the map at all times, but I'm wandering around with Ada now so we'll see what happens when I get back to Hangman's Alley.

Comment: Exactly :) not sure how the tracking part factors in, there's only one way to find out I guess. If this doesn't work there may be other solutions, but so far all the other ones I've come across used console commands.

Comment: Travelling would also be my suggestion. You can't dismiss a companion through the dialogue with another potential companion? I can't remember.

Comment: If you have enough charisma to form caravans between settlements, you should be able to assign him to lead a caravan, which would get him moving. Other than that, staying far away from an area long enough should make things respawn. Similar to what happens if you kill key NPCs inside a city etc - stay well clear of the place long enough and they'll be back.